# Is it possible to work with just div class for separating common styles, without using tables?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a basic email template. I have written styles for this email template by writing header, body, footer, sidebar and the main tag container. Here's my code:

```html
<html>

<head>

<style>

.container {
 position:relative;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 color: #000; 
 align-items:center;
    }
     
 .sidebar {
   position:absolute;
   top:402px;
   bottom:0px;
   left:775px;
   width:180px;
   background:violet;
  
   
  }
 .header{
   min-height:400px;
   width:957px;
   background-color:aqua;
      }
   
 .body{
   margin-top:400px;
   min-height:500px;
   width:732px;
   background-color:light-blue;
      }
   
  
 .footer{
   margin-top:900px;
   max-height:250px;
   background-color:grey;
   width:732px;
   }
   
 
   
h3
 {
 color:#660066;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:24px;
 text-align:center;
 
 }
  
  
p
 {
 font-size:12;
 font-family:Arial;
 color:#333;
 
 
 }
 
a:link, a:visited,a:active 
 {
 color:#660066;
 }
  

 
table {
 min-width:100px;
 border:none;
 
 } 

}



}
</style>


</head>


<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="header">

   <p>This div section is associated to header...</p>

  </div>
  
  <div class="sidebar"> 
  
   Only side bar contents will be placed here...
  
  
  </div>

  <div class="body">
   
   
  
   <h3>Sample Heading</h3>
   <p>This DIV section is associated to body. This DIV section is associated to body...This DIV section is associated to body...This DIV section is associated to body...This DIV section is associated to body...This DIV section is associated to body...This DIV section is associated to body...This DIV section is associated to body. 
   
   This DIV section is associated to body. This DIV section is associated to body...This DIV section is associated to body...This DIV section is associated to body...This DIV section is associated to body...This DIV section is associated to body...This DIV section is associated to body...This DIV section is associated to body.
       
  
 
  
 </div>
 
  
  <br>
  </p>
        <div class="footer">
        
            This DIV section is associated to footer...
            
        </div>
 </div>
 
 
</body>


</html>
```

Now I'm trying to center these whole div elements, is it possible to do this without tables, and just with div tags?

Thank you
Tayyab

Comment: My aim is just how to center these div elements without using tables...

Comment: .container{ margin:0 auto; width:1000px;}

Comment: Why is it necessary to put 1000px width. Any idea?

Comment: You can give any value as width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.container{
     width:960px; // or you can also use min-width:800
     margin:0 auto;
}
```

If it doesn't work try by removing position.